# java script, SCRIPT1002 in ie10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

i'm using ReactJs for making Web Front.

my problem is just not working in Internet Explorer and safari.

my codes is working very well in Chrome and Firefox.

but not working in Internet Explorer and Safari...

error coid :

"SCRIPT1002: syntax error"

```
(() => {
   /*
    ......
   */
})()
```

i think that Internet Explorer and safari do not support Anonymous Function in javascript.

but i don't know how fix it...

how can i fix it ?

thx ~

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function is not supported by IE & Safari

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[image]